# Numbering table rows

Tags: 8, views, theming

Views are normally formatted as unformatted list. I would format a view as HTML list, and choose between `<ul>` or `<ol>` markup.

Since I use the [DraggableViews](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews) module, I need to format the view as table. I would like to have some automatic numbering for the view's table rows, similar to the HTML list, which uses `<ol>` and `<li>` markup.

How could I get each row in the view table to have a number that is automatically increased?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the global *view result counter* field to the view, whose description in the *Add fields* dialog box is the following.

> Displays the actual position of the view result.

> [image: screenshot]